# Husky: pre-commit hook starts the bash script, but does not wait for user selection

Tags: bash, npm, husky

When I do a commit, the bash script starts but doesn't wait for the user to choose

.huskyrc  file

```
{
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "bash scripts/pre_commit.sh"
  }
}
```

pre_commit.sh  file

```
   #!/bin/bash

    PS3='Please enter your choice: '
    options=("X" "Y" "Z")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            "X")
                echo "works"
                exit 0                                            
                ;;
            "Y")
                npm run test
                exit 0  
                ;;
            "Z")
                echo "Option Z";
                exit 0                                               
                ;;
            *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
        esac
    done
    exit 0
```

Comment: While I have never worked with a git precommit hook, I could imagine that git binds stdin to something else than your tty when running the hook. At the very least, you should verify that this is the case and throw an error message if it is not, i.e. `[[ -t 1 ]] || echo NOT A TERMINAL`

Answer (score 2):

The answer was add befor PS3='Please enter your choice: '

## Allows us to read user input below, assigns stdin to keyboard

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  exec < /dev/tty
fi
```